# Question about Ask Different account merging

Tags: support, user-accounts

I've created a second account by mistake and now I'm logged into it and cannot get out to log in the correct one. Can I merge the two or delete the one that I'm now logged in? I receive emails about comments on my own question (posted with an old real account) and cannot even comment or exchange with the people trying to help me!!

Comment: It says that I'm user3116426 - that's exactly the wrong account.
On another account I go by my real name - Alexei Zoubov
Here is the link to my original question posted with the correct account:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297071/apache-errors-on-macos-sierra?noredirect=1#comment375483_297071

Answer (score 2):

In general the “my account” section of the help has the procedures to register, merge and delete accounts.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help

If you can register your current account with the same email address (or just an email address) that [helps verify and merge the two or more accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) that are easy to make if you don’t register initially.

In a nutshell, you can request merge in the contact us link at the bottom of any page.

If the Alexei Zoubov account is the one you want to use, but the one your browser has you logged into is something else, then you can try logging out of that and logging back in with the correct one. If you’re not sure you can log in, request a merge from the old account before you log out.

To do this:

1. Click on the Stack Exchange menu at top left (see image below):

[image]

2. After clicking on it you'll get access to the Log Out option:

[image]

3. Select Log Out. You should see a prompt with a blue Log Out button. Above that you'll have a checkbox option for *Log out on all devices* which you may want to tick before logging out.
4. Once you're logged out, you can log in by clicking on the Log In option at the top of the page:

[image]

5. Now enter the email address and password of your Alexei Zoubov account and click on the blue Log In button.

You should now have access to the correct account again. Please let me know if you run into any problems.

**NOTE:** I did try checking both the user3116426 and user253102 accounts, but these do not seem to have been registered.